# What is best timing for thread.join?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to know which way is better performance, the code1 is as below, join them after all threads started.

```
ts = []
for href in hrefs:
    t = create_thread_parse(href)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    ts.append(t)

for t in ts:
    t.join()
```

The code2 as below, join it after thread started.

```
ts = []
for p, href in enumerate(hrefs):
    t = create_thread_parse(href)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    ts.append(t)
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

They do different things.

[`t.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) blocks until the `t` thread terminates. So your 1st version runs the threads in parallel, then waits for them all to finish. The 2nd version runs the threads one after the other, a new thread isn't created or started until the previous one terminates.